# How to becomeresponder from one UITextView to another UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have two `UITextView`'s in my iPhone app. When the user selects one `UITextView` the controller automatically goes to another `UITextView`. I have tried the following way in my project. But the second `UITextView` does not `becomefirstresponder` until the user clicks inside the second `UITextView`.

```
 -(void) viewDidLoad
{   
    TextView1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 320, 300, 50)];
    TextView1.delegate = self;
    TextView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    TextView1.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    TextView1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    TextView1.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [self.view addSubview: TextView1];

    TextView2 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 30)];
    TextView2.delegate = self;
    TextView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    TextView2.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    TextView2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightTextColor].CGColor;
    TextView2.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [self.view addSubview: TextView2];

    UIBarButtonItem *textBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: TextView2];

    accessoryToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    accessoryToolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textBarButton, nil];
}

 -(BOOL) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"TextView Should Begin Editing");
    if (textView == messageTextView) 
    {
        [TextView2 setInputAccessoryView:accessoryToolBar];
        [TextView1 resignFirstResponder];
        [TextView2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        [TextView2 setInputAccessoryView:accessoryToolBar];
        [TextView1 resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the complete `textViewShouldBeginEditing` method. That's the wrong point.

You want, that as soon, as the user touches the first textView, the second one should be selected, right? If that is what you want, use `textViewDidBeginEditing:`instead.

```
- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
  if(textView == TextView1) {
    [TextView2 becomeFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

That should be everything you need.

Comment: Hello Mr.Jaydee3 Thanks for your helpful answer. It is working. Thanks again.